# Make Action for 3 Button in one form

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem for input Form with 3 Button.

I have 3 Button:

`approved | rejected | deleted`

Then my form in modal bootstrap, with form like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="input-item input-with-label">
        <label class="input-item-label">Admin Note</label>
        <textarea name="notes" class="input-bordered input-textarea input-textarea-sm"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="btn-grp guttar-20px list-unstyled">
            <li><button name="status" value="Approved" class="form-progress-btn btn btn-success btn-md text-uppercase">Approve</button></li>
            <li><button name="status" value="Warning" class="form-progress-btn btn btn-grey btn-md text-uppercase">Missing</button></li>
            <li><button name="status" value="Rejected" class="form-progress-btn btn btn-danger btn-md text-uppercase">Reject</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I have controller like this:

```
switch($request->status) {
    case 'Approved': 
    break;
    case 'Rejected': 
    break;
    case 'Warning': 
    break;
}
```

But this is not working. So how do I make a multiple button in one form for action to update?

Comment: You can't have the same `name` for your buttons. That's what is submitted, so they should be unique.

Comment: Then what if I use a different `name` to make `$request` on the controller?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure your form shouldn't even submit. A regular `button` doesn't perform that action. You need to specify the `type="submit"`. For future reference: simply saying something does not work is too vague. Always specify in what way it does not work.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot `type="submit"` because I use form with ajax. So how do I solve my problem to use these three buttons? I have tried changing to `type` and different `name` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If it's an AJAX form, then show the AJAX as well, so that we know in what way you're sending the data. This way we have to guess.

Comment: Assign data-status to each button like (approved, rejected,warning) and then on click fetch data-status and assign to status variable. pass status variable to controller and conditionally check status value

Comment: @El_Vanja your statement is incorrect. `<button>` is by specification *Type Submit* without any `type` attribute. That's why we always enforce the use of `type="button"` (which might seem redundant at first) exactly to prevent that *Submit* behavior - when necessary.

Comment: @IrshadKhan can you added an detailed for `data-status` ? so i will try it

Comment: Check answer I have post it

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I see. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="input-item input-with-label">
    <label class="input-item-label">Admin Note</label>
    <textarea name="notes" class="input-bordered input-textarea input-textarea-sm"></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="btn-grp guttar-20px list-unstyled">
        <li><button name="status" data-status="approved" id"approved" value="Approved" class="form-progress-btn btn btn-success btn-md text-uppercase">Approve</button></li>
        <li><button name="status" data-status="warning" id="warning" value="Warning" class="form-progress-btn btn btn-grey btn-md text-uppercase">Missing</button></li>
        <li><button name="status" data-status="rejected" id="rejected" value="Rejected" class="form-progress-btn btn btn-danger btn-md text-uppercase">Reject</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and write jquery code

```
$("#approved, #rejected, #warning").on("click", function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    const status = $(this).data("status");
    callFunctionForAjax(status)
});

function callFunctionForAjax(status){
    // your ajax logic here
    console.log(status);
}
```

Comment: So call value with `$(this).data('status')` like that?

Comment: yes it will return clicked button data status value

Comment: Is it helpful for you?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are right now i have updated it. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The above (although I fixed some typos) is still not a perfect answer. You don't need a *click* - you should not rely on a button CLICK to prevent a form default submit and use AJAX instead. A Form can be submitted even without a button click, you can also hit enter while focused inside an `<input>` remember? ;) The handler should instead be on the form's `"submit"` event. But that's than another story.